# Attaching dynamically a div at the bottom of an opened Select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down list which I'm trying to attach a div to it when the list is shown. For this, I have the events `onDropdownShow` and `onDropdownHide`. 
 When the list is not loaded the div should disappear as well. How would I display/hide the div at the bottom of the shown list? Any ideas?

[image]

references

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect/blob/master/jquery.multiselect.js'></script>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example-post-checkboxName').multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableClickableOptGroups: true,
        enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        onDropdownShow: function (select, container) {
                //show div
        },
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
           // hide div
        }
            });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Multiselect</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div id="theParentx">
                <select id="example-post-checkboxName" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                      <optgroup label="The group">
                      <option>a</option>
                      <option>b</option>
                      <option>c</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
                <div id="theChildx" class="testStyle">
                     -> the attached div <-
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$('#theChildx').hide()` --- `$('#theChildx').show()`

Comment: @DaniP yes, sure, but the major problem is getting the coordinates of the bottom of the loaded 'select' list and displaying the div there. The list is dynamic so it's length will vary.

Comment: Good point ... maybe checking the height of the optgroup ? .can you recreate on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set that div and position absolute based on the `heights` for the multiselect. Check this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example-post-checkboxName').multiselect({
    onDropdownShow: function (select, container) {
        var siz = parseInt($('#theParentx').height(),10) + parseInt($('#theParentx .multiselect-container').height(),10) + parseInt($('#theChildx').height(),10);
        $('#theChildx').css('top',siz+"px").show();
    },
    onDropdownHide: function (event) {
        $('#theChildx').hide()
    }
  });
});
```

---

[**DemoFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLXr6/21/)

Comment: Great answer. However the width is not the same as the top list's. How would I match that as well? * I wasn't able to create the fiddle earlier due to the reference.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET same way store the width of the multiselect on a var an apply it to the div http://jsfiddle.net/bLXr6/22/

Comment: that is a great answer. Huge contribution.